# Fast looping through Python dataframe with previous row reference

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with two columns: ID and Days. DataFrame is sorted by ascending order in both variables. For example:

```
# Initial dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat([1, 2 ,3], 4),
                 'day': [1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4, 12, 15, 1, 20, 21, 24]})

    id  day
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   10
3   1   11
4   2   3
5   2   4
6   2   12
7   2   15
8   3   1
9   3   20
10  3   21
11  3   24
```

I want to add a third column, which would give a "session" number for every ID*day. By "session" i mean a sequence of days with difference less than 2 days between days of one session. For example, sequence `5,6,7` will be considered as one session, while `5,6,9` will be considered as two sessions and should be marked as `0, 0, 1`, i.e. day 5 and 6 were refered toi session #0, while day 9 was refered to session #1.
Session numbers shuould start from `0` for each new ID.

In other words, what i want to get is:

```
    id  day session
0   1   1   0
1   1   2   0
2   1   10  1
3   1   11  1
4   2   3   0
5   2   4   0
6   2   12  1
7   2   15  2  
8   3   1   0
9   3   20  1
10  3   21  1
11  3   24  2
```

To solve this task I use basic for loop. In this loop i iteratevely run through all unique IDs, then subset a block of data from initial dataset and assign session numbers for every day of a specific ID. The problem i have - since the initial dataset is millions of lines - **loop takes a looot of time**! For example, for 1 mln of lines my loop spends about a minute, which is too much.

**How to improve the speed?** Any method is good! If you know how to achieve desired result, for instance, with some numpy matrix manipulations which will reduce time - also good ...

My code for the loop:

```
# Get sessions for every id
sessions = []
for i in data.id.unique():
    id_data = data['day'][data['id']==i].reset_index(drop=True)
    for ind in id_data.index:
        if ind == 0:
            temp = [0]
        elif ((id_data[ind] - id_data[ind - 1]) < 2):
            temp.append(temp[ind - 1])
        else:
            temp.append(temp[ind - 1] + 1)
    sessions.extend(temp)

# Add sessions to the table
data['session'] = sessions
```

Comment: `data['session'] = np.where(data['day'].shift(1) > data['day'], 1, 0)` starts you off, the increment in `session` is causing me a little issue :)

Comment: Mind testing all the solutions presented here on your data and then accepting the best one based on your timings?

Comment: @coldspeed , yes, this will be a good illustration of problem solutions! I can do that, but tomorrow i think. Its night right now in my country, so i will go to sleep ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` twice with `np.where()`, `diff()` and `cumsum()`:

```
data['session'] = np.where(data.groupby('id')['day'].diff().fillna(0)>1, 1, 0)
data['session'] = data.groupby('id')['session'].cumsum()
```

Yields:

```
    id  day  session
0    1    1        0
1    1    2        0
2    1   10        1
3    1   11        1
4    2    3        0
5    2    4        0
6    2   12        1
7    2   15        2
8    3    1        0
9    3   20        1
10   3   21        1
11   3   24        2
```

Comment: `data.groupby('id')['day'].diff().fillna(0).gt(1).astype(int)` might also work.

Answer (score 8):

You can sum Boolean

```
data.groupby('id').day.apply(lambda x : x.diff().gt(1).cumsum())
Out[614]: 
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     2
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    2
Name: day, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 5):

We can take advantage of the fact that your data is sorted to eliminate the `fillna`, reduce two `groupby` calls to one, and eliminate the need for `apply`.

```
df['session'] = df.day.diff().ge(2)
df['session'] = df.groupby('id').session.cumsum()
```

```
df
    id  day  session
0    1    1      0.0
1    1    2      0.0
2    1   10      1.0
3    1   11      1.0
4    2    3      0.0
5    2    4      0.0
6    2   12      1.0
7    2   15      2.0
8    3    1      0.0
9    3   20      1.0
10   3   21      1.0
11   3   24      2.0
```

In return, `"session"` will be a float column.

Comment: hi, @coldspeed, you missed the grouping in `df.groupby('id').day.diff().ge(2)`. If dont group by user, then in cases when there is a less than 2 days diff between values of `day`column session indecator is not reset to zero